Is it at all possible to use less than 50 GB for an instance boot volume?
I want to create an Oracle Cloud Compute Instance that uses less than 50 GB of space. I only need about 10 GB.
Most information I'm finding on the Internet states that the boot volume on OCI can not be less than 50 GB.
However, https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/oracle-cloud-block-storage-size-question/9614/7
says:

In OCI, the boot volume size is goverend by the source image you use. If you use an Oracle-provided image, they are all smaller than 50 GB for historical reasons (until a recent OCI update, boot columes could not exceed 50 GB in size.

I checked the Debian image I'm using and from what I understand, it says it needs at least 2 GB only:
# wget https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/cloud/bookworm/latest/debian-12-generic-arm64.qcow2
# qemu-img info debian-12-generic-arm64.qcow2
image: debian-12-generic-arm64.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 2.0G (2147483648 bytes)
disk size: 409M
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false

Still, OCI creates 50 GB boot volumes. Is there any way to instruct the system to create a 10 GB boot volume?
(As a side note, my own instances are 47 GB if I don't change the devault volume size suggested when I create them. So it is possible to have a boot volume less than 50 GB?)

I tried to pick the right SE website to post this question. Stackoverflow has the most eyeballs but I think won't accept a question not about programming. Serverfault seems not a good match either. So I ended up here. If there's a better place, please let me know

Hi Menov, I think this would be a question for Oracle support?

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with Unix or Linux. If not SO or SF, then [su] might work, but cloud computing in general seems to be on-topic on SF: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7907/is-serverfault-the-best-place-for-cloud-computing-platform-questions
